# Passing view from one controller to another controller's view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to pass another controller's view to the first controller's view? I have controller1 with view1. I need to call another controller2 action method from view1 and pass the view2 to a div in view 1.

I tried `@html.Action("action","controller")`. This called controller 2, but was not passing the view2 to view1.

Am I doing it wrong? How can I do that?

Comment: You can use Tempdata to pass data from one controller action to another controller action to view. You can use Session variable to pass data across all pages.

Comment: Side note: you really should not call controllers from view... At very least it is not possible to safely call asynchronous actions from the view... and in ideally view should just render data and not have any business logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time on the code and a bit of googling, I figured out my issue.
The child action method I was calling from parent view was an async method, so I did something like the below,

Parent view

```
<div id="childView"></div>
```

Ajax Call to populate the parent view

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url : '@Url.Action(actionName: "ChildAction", controllerName: "ChildController")',
        dataType: "html",
        async:true,
        success: function (result) { $("#childView").html(result); }
        });

 });
```

Hope it will be useful for some one.

Comment: Typically you would create a partial view and put it in a shared folder for clarity. Create the Action in a base controller and have any controller who may use it inherit the action

Answer (score 0):

This example is something you can use.  I did not put it into an ASP.NET Fiddle because we are dealing with TWO view.

Controller/ViewModel of First

```
namespace Testy20161006.Controllers
{
    //I'm showing how to pass data from one Controller Action to another Controller Action.
    //With the data you can render your second view however you like with the data.
    //We pass data NOT views.  You could use a partial view, but I am showing the most basic way.
    public class NewbieDevViewModel
    {
        public String DataToPassToNewControllerAction { get; set; }
    }

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //I am using Tut145 for my first Controller/Action/View, but you could have called it Index
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Tut145(NewbieDevViewModel passedData)
        {
            //passing simple string, so I can pass it using my QueryString
            return RedirectToAction("MyAction2", "Home2", new { passedData = passedData.DataToPassToNewControllerAction });
        }

        public ActionResult Tut145()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

View of First

```
@model Testy20161006.Controllers.NewbieDevViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Tut145 - View 1</title>
   </head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(r=>r.DataToPassToNewControllerAction)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.DataToPassToNewControllerAction, new { @Value = "ValueOfData" })
        <input type="submit" value="Submit data - to send to new Controller Action" />
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Controller of Second

```
namespace Testy20161006.Controllers
{
    public class Home2Controller : Controller
    {
        //I named my Controller Home2 and Action MyAction2, but you can name it anything you want
        public ActionResult MyAction2(string passedData)
        {
            //reconstruct the ViewModel and pass into second view
            NewbieDevViewModel viewModel = new NewbieDevViewModel { DataToPassToNewControllerAction = passedData };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

View of Second

```
@model Testy20161006.Controllers.NewbieDevViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>MyAction2 </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        - Final View - I passed data into here from different Controller Action -and-
        I can render this page anyway I which
    </div>
    <p/>
    @Html.LabelFor(r => r.DataToPassToNewControllerAction)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.DataToPassToNewControllerAction)
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial view can be used to render a view inside another view. Create a partial view for an action in controller 2. Call that partial view from the view of controller 1.
Here is the example :

First Controller :

```
public class Controller1Controller : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        return View();
    }
 }
```

First Controller View :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Controller 1 View</h4>
    <hr />
    <h1>Fisrt Controller</h1>
    <div>
        @{
            Html.RenderAction("GetSubject", "Controller2");
        }
    </div>               
</div>
```

}

Second Controller  :

```
 public class Controller2Controller : Controller
 {       
    public ActionResult GetSubject()
    {
        Subject s = new Subject() { id = 2, SubjectName = "XYZ" };
        return PartialView(s);
    }        
 }
```

Second Controller View :

```
<div>
    <h4>Controller 2 view</h4>
<hr />
    <h1>Second Controller</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Piyali, thanks for the reply. The above works on a normal child view. But my child view has an async method which calls an API. So I am getting an error "'HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked while waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete.'". Do you have any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: Also thought I will mention, my child view is not partial view, its a normal view

Comment: I figured it out,see the answer below.

Comment: Thank you @NewbieDev for your response.